# JTextField doesn't seem to fire PropertyChangeEvent

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to create a swing form where the text fields are connected to a bean using the bensbindings framework. I have set this up in the Netbeans matisse editor. However, changing the content of a JTextField doesn't seem to update the bean.

Trying just a simple case of a JTextField with a PropertyChangeListener, there never occurs any property change events as text is input. When are these events fired? Or is it only possible to bind from a bean to the text field and not the other way?

What is the prefered way of getting the content of a JTextField to update a Bean? IS it doing it manually when a button is pressed?

I am pretty new to swing, and I want to learn how to use beansbindings and the Better Swing Application Framework to build an application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As specified by [JTextComponent#setText](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#setText%28java.lang.String%29):

> Note that text is not a bound property, so no PropertyChangeEvent is fired when it changes. To listen for changes to the text, use DocumentListener.

Comment: Seems you are right. I don't know how beansbindings framework is supposed to work with JTextField with this limitation. I guess it's only one way (bean -> text field).

Answer (score 1):

Try to add a DocumentListener to the JTextField's document. The listener is invoked on type/remove, cut/paste.